# Cocoa: programmatically show the main window after closing it with X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I want to programmatically re-open the main window of my Cocoa application after the user closed it with the X button.
I know it's still somewhere in memory but I don't know where.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using the default Cocoa Application template, your app delegate has a reference to the window that's in MainMenu.xib. You can simply call

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

perhaps in an `IBAction` triggered by a menu item, to reopen the window. Note: be sure that the "Release when closed" and "One shot" boxes are unchecked in IB.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. I created a new app using the template. I'm not entirely sure where the above should go. Is it supposed to be somewhere in my AppDelegate class? Does that class continue to "run" even after the window is closed?

Comment: Yes and yes. There's an object in your nib that is an instance of the app delegate; it's generally alive the entire time your program is running.

Comment: Thanks for this! Helps me! I almost forgot that makeKeyAndOrderFront method

Comment: That will only work if window was not released - which can happen and is a viable option for windows.

Answer (score 5):

Surely, if the user closes a window they want it to go away. Reopening a window they just closed will most likely annoy them. If you, the programmer, disrespect their wishes, they will probably disrespect your program by moving it to the Trash.

If you want to make it impossible to close the main window, disable the close button.  You can do this easily in interface builder on the Window attributes inspector.

Comment: The admonition is generally sound, but I'm not sure that the question was "How can I give the user the finger by not allowing the window to be closed?" I read it as being "The user might need to re-display the window after having closed it. How do I do this?" (See, e.g., Activity Monitor, among others, for this behavior -- there is a menu item that will bring back the primary app window after it has been closed.)

Comment: I am not trying to push the window to the user. I am trying to trigger it programmatically after they click a button that will say "Open".

Comment: I agree Jeremy, but Apple does not. I think their HIG requirements are kind of wacked, but if I want them publish my stuff in the App Store, then on the occasions where they decide to invoke HIG guidelines (such as during submissions meant to fix actual bugs in otherwise previously approved apps), then you can either awakeFromNib or gtfo, I guess. I have a tear of rage in the back of my eye over my latest round with them. But, they win. I want to be in the App Store a lot more than I want to stick it to them.

Comment: It greatly depends on the scenario. If user drops a file over its App icon in the dock, or in the finder - and the app's window has been closed previously, that's almost precisely as telling the application "Please open this file in a new window". The scenario is automatically taken care of when you're a "Document based app", but if you only have one "main" window hard-wired - you'll need to re-open that window yourself for displaying the new content.

Comment: This answer is not answering the question posed. Seems this should be a comment on the main question if anything. 

Anyway, there are legitimate reasons to re-open an app's main window. For example, if an app's main window gets closed but still has a Status Bar Item with functionality to reopen the main window.

Comment: @AndresCanella Yes it does. The last paragraph answers it: disable the close button so it can't be pressed.

Comment: @JeremyP The question is asking how to 'show main window after closing', not forcibly prevent it from closing. Nathan further clarifies that here in this thread.