# How do you re-open a closed window created in the storyboard in OS X

Tags: macos, swift, xcode-storyboard

My question is essential this question, but the answer doesn't seem to work with Swift/Storyboards.
[Cocoa: programmatically show the main window after closing it with X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201958/cocoa-programmatically-show-the-main-window-after-closing-it-with-x)

Basically, I have a more or less default application with a menu, a window, and a ViewController. If the user closes the window while the application is running, how do I reopen it?

I have created an action in the app delegate the connects to the "Open" Menu Item. Within this function, I would like to ensure that the window is visible. So if the user has closed it, it should reappear. But I cannot figure out how to access the closed window. Storyboard does not seem to allow me to create an outlet for my Window in my app delegate.

Answer (score 6):

This is quite simple to archive, even it is not an elegant solution. Add a new property to your app delegate for your main window controller. In the following example, I call the controller `MainWindowController`.

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var mainWindowController: MainWindowController? = nil
    func applicationShouldHandleReopen(sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {
        mainWindowController?.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        return false
    }
}
```

In the initialisation of the main window controller I register the controller in the app delegate:

```
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        // ...initialisation...
        // Register the controller in the app delegate
        let appDelegate = NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.mainWindowController = self
    }
}
```

That is all, works perfectly for me.