# How to Make macOS App Window Hidden When Closed and Reopened With Menu Bar Item?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am developing a macOS app (using Swift & Storyboard) which window behaves like the Adobe Creative Cloud app. And I could not find the optimal solution after hours of research.

This means:

1. When the app launches, the main window shows up with various menus on the status bar, an icon appears in the dock, and an icon appears in the status bar.
2. When the user clicks the red X, the main window and the icon in the dock are hidden.
3. The main app window can be reopened by clicking the status bar icon. And the dock icon reappears.

My storyboard looks like this:
[image]

I have tried the following:

1. By setting `Application is agent (UIElement)` to `YES`, I was able to close the main app window while keeping the app alive. However, the app icon does not show up in the dock, and there are no menus in the left side of the status bar.
2. I was able to launch a new app window by clicking the status bar icon. But doing so simply opens a whole new window regardless of whether a window is already being presented (I only want one window to show up).

```
let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
guard let window = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: .init(stringLiteral: "main")) as? WindowController else { return }
window.showWindow(self)
```

Much appreciation for anyone who can help!

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you re-open a closed window created in the storyboard in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595478/how-do-you-re-open-a-closed-window-created-in-the-storyboard-in-os-x)

Comment: @Willeke You didn't read the last part of the question

Comment: I did read your question. What makes you think I didn't?

Comment: @Willeke This question is about deactivating and activating the app from a `NSStatusItem` in the menubar, including hiding / unhiding the dock icon, while your suggested duplicate is about a standard close and open window scenario.

Comment: The question is "How to Make macOS App Window Hidden When Closed and Reopened With Menu Bar?". It's about a window.

Comment: @Wendel: please add " Item" at the end of your question, to prevent duplicate complains.

Comment: Yeah I could have described my question a little better, but it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the `Application is agent` approach, but change the `activationPolicy` of the `NSApp`.

To dynamically hide the icon after closing the (last) window use this in your AppDelegate:

```
func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.accessory)
    return false
}
```

And use something simular to this to initialise your menubar icon and activate the window including a dock icon:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var status: NSStatusItem?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        status = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        status?.button?.title = "Test"
        status?.button?.action = #selector(activateWindow(_:))
        status?.button?.target = self
    }

    @IBAction func activateWindow(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            NSApp.windows.first?.orderFrontRegardless()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is almost what I needed. However, after ```activateWindow``` ran, the window does not reappear. App icon does appear in the dock and menus do show up in the status bar.

Comment: @Wendell Maybe `NSApp.windows.first` is empty? In that case you have to recreate the window, or make sure you haven't removed your initial window from memory.

Comment: I used ```if let window = NSApp.windows.first {``` to check ```NSApp.windows.first```, and it is not nil...

Comment: @Wendell Try `window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)`

Comment: If you meant ```NSApp.windows.first?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)```, it is still the same problem.

Comment: @Wendell I have extended my answer a bit. Just paste this in a new project. I have tested on my side, running macOS 11.

Comment: Yeah, your solution does work in a new project I created. I will give it to you!