# How to reopen an macos App using menubar button

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I created an app with a menubar button using swift and storyboard, when I click the close button the window closed and the menubar button still sits on the menubar, that's good. What I want to do next is reopen the window by clicking the menubar button. After searching I figured out I can use this code to bring it to the front, but it only works when the window is still open. How can I bring it back when it is closed or miniatured?

```
NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```

This the appDelegate

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

private var statusItem: NSStatusItem!

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    
    statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: 16.0)
    if let button = statusItem.button {
        button.image = NSImage(named: "remote-control")
        button.image?.size = NSSize(width: 16.0, height: 16.0)
        button.image?.isTemplate = true

        button.action = #selector(bringToFront(sender:))
    }
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
    print("terminate")
}

func applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(_ app: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    return true
}

@objc func bringToFront(sender: AnyObject?) {
    NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    NSApp.windows.last?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
}}
```

This is the windowcontroller

```
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
    
    window?.title = ""
    let styleMask: NSWindow.StyleMask = [.closable, .titled, .miniaturizable]
    window?.styleMask = styleMask
}}
```

Thanks

Comment: How is the first window created?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you re-open a closed window created in the storyboard in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595478/how-do-you-re-open-a-closed-window-created-in-the-storyboard-in-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
In appdelegate use deminiaturize function does exactly what I want.

```
    for window in NSApp.windows {
        window.deminiaturize(nil)
    }
```

Since I only have one window but NSApp.windows has two members, I think I can deminiatureize all the windows.