# Show and hide app on close click without terminating in cocoa app

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am working on macos swift project in which i am using red cross button to hide window and remain open in background (app doc icon with dot below)
i am facing an issue when i reopen it from dock icon app delegate function shows that app is in foreground but not showing app in foreground
Here is my code which am using in viewContoller with NSWindowDelegate **Delegate=self**
Thanks in advance

i am trying this to hide But dont know why when i click on dock app icon app is not opening again

```
 func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
        NSApp.hide(nil)
    return true

    }
```

Comment: The app and the window are two seperate things. Closing the window doesn't hide anything and unhiding the app doesn't open the window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you re-open a closed window created in the storyboard in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595478/how-do-you-re-open-a-closed-window-created-in-the-storyboard-in-os-x)